# Usar o array_key_exists

Tags: php

estou tentando verificar se algum valor existe em um array no 1 array consigo verificar se existe mais quando o array tem outro array dentro não consigo verificar se existe.

1 array

```
$array = array("Volvo" => 'BMW', "BMW" => 'X5');

array (size=2)
  'Volvo' => string 'XC90' (length=4)
  'BMW' => string 'X5' (length=2)
```

resultado do 1 array

```
if (array_key_exists("Volvo",$array):                           
      echo "existe!";                           
  else :                            
      echo "não existe!";
  endif;

// resultado "existe"
```

2 array

```
$array = array(array('volvo' => 'XC90'), array('BMW' => 'X5'));

0 => 
    array (size=1)
      volvo' => string 'XC90' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'BMW' => string 'X5' (length=4)
```

resultado do 2 array

```
if (array_key_exists("Volvo",$array):                           
    echo "existe!";                           
else :                            
    echo "não existe!";
endif;


// resultado "não existe"
```

Comment: a verdade q o erro todo do seu codigo é que volvo ta minusculo e você ta chamando ele como maiusculo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Código de uma resposta no SO<sup>en</sup>: [Check if specific array key exists in multidimensional array - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420715/check-if-specific-array-key-exists-in-multidimensional-array-php)

```
function findKey($array, $keySearch)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($key === $keySearch) {
            return true;
        } elseif (is_array($item) && findKey($item, $keySearch)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(findKey($array, 'Volvo'));
```

<sup>***Observação: Essa resposta leva em conta somente se o valor procurado é o igual ao pesquisado.***</sup>

Comment: obrigado testei e deu certo .

Comment: E se pesquisar por `true`? Usar a comparação frouxa é bastante perigosa nessas situações.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não concordo com bastante perigoso, tudo depende do contexto, talvez a pessoa não queria testar o tipo e valor somente o valor. Vale lembrar que a resposta é retirada na integra do SOen e colocada aqui igualzinha dando a credibilidade adequada ... Mesmo não tendo validade o que falou eu coloquei mais um igual que eu sei que testa valor e tipo.

Comment: Perigoso no sentido de abrir brechas para efeitos colaterais que podem ser difíceis de identificar na aplicação e dar manutenção.

Answer (score 3):

Este é o comportamento esperado, não existe chave "Volvo" na array inicial. Se você tem uma array dentro da outra (array multidimensional) você deve verificar cada array, basta fazer um loop.

Quando você faz:

```
$array = [['volvo' => 'XC90'], ['BMW' => 'X5']];
```

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
$array = [0 => ['volvo' => 'XC90'], 1 => ['BMW' => 'X5']];
```

Por isso fazer: `array_key_exists(1, $array);` retornará verdadeiro, para esses dois casos acima.

---

Se você quiser busca a chave de array dentro de outra array pode fazer:

```
function multi_array_key_exists($key, array $array) : bool {
    // Pesquisamos no array atual:      
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        return true;
    }

    foreach ($array as $v) {    

        // Chamamos a função novamente, para que ele continue a busca no array interno:
        if (is_array($v) && multi_array_key_exists($key, $v)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta consegui resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, a solução para seu problema é mais simples do que parece. Você deve criar uma função que percorra todo o array (usando o `foreach`) e verifique se aquele determinado índice é um array (para isso vamos utilizar a função `is_array`), se o elemento verificado for um array ele chama a função novamente passando esse elemento como array principal. Se não, ele compara o índice do elemento verificado com aquele valor passado. Veja:

```php
function verificaArray($array, $elemento){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if(!is_array($value)){ // verifica se elemento atual não é um array
            if($key === $elemento){ // se o elemento a ser procurado for igual ao do índice atual
                return true; // Se achou retorna true
            }else{
                end($array);

                if($key === key($array)){
                    return false; // se não acho e estiver no último elemento, retorna falso
                }
            }
        }else{
            return verificaArray ($value, $elemento); // Chama a função para fazer tudo de novo quando é array
        }
    }
}

$a = []; // seu array aqui 

if(verificaArray($a, "Volvo")){
    echo "Existe";
}else{
    echo "Não existe";
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Teste a entrada `['Foo' => 'Bar', 'Volvo' => 1]`; mesmo procurando por `Volvo` a saída será `Não existe`. Além dos erros de sintaxe, você precisa rever o seu `return false`.

Comment: ao executar o código realmente retorna não existe com erro de sintaxe pensei que tinha funcionado só que não tinha salvo o código antes agora salvei e deu esse erro

Comment: Olá amigos, obrigado por me informarem meus erros. Creio eu que já foram corrigidos. De qualquer maneira obrigado por tornar a comunidade melhor!

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar determinada chave de um array multidimensional é necessário utilizar a recursividade e a função `array_key_exists` não faz isso.

```
function array_key_exists_recursive($needle, array $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $needle) return $value;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if ($x = array_key_exists_recursive($key, $value)) return $x;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Quando você transformou esse método de alguma classe sua em função esqueceu de acertar o conteúdo da função removendo o `$this` dela. Seu código do jeito que está irá lançar um erro fatal `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context...` pois você está usando `$this` fora do contexto de uma classe.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela observação @Vinicius.Silva. Corrigi o erro.

Comment: Mesmo assim não é motivo algum dar voto negativo, é só avisar!

Comment: Estava tentando dar scroll no pad do notebook e acabou gerando clique e o SO não me deixava remover o downvote (que já foi removido) até que você editasse a resposta.

Comment: Um detalhe muito importante é que a função não retornará `true` quando encontrar, mas sim o próprio valor encontrado, então cuidados como não fazer `$resultado === true` devem ser tomados.

Comment: E @VictorCarnaval, recomendo manter o `===`, pois com apenas dois isso pode acontecer: `array_key_exists_recursive(true, ['Volvo' => 'Foo'])` retornar `Foo`

Comment: Entendi @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado pela explicação.